# Linux unary operator to check exitence of file with pattern name

Tags: linux, file, pattern-matching, unary-operator

I´d like to check if there is any file whose name matches a given pattern, in a given path.

```
assert=1
myPatternpath=$HOME/folderName/abcMYPATTERN.xml
if [ ! -f $myPatternpath ] 
then assert=0 
fi
echo $assert;
```

MYPATTERN should be any character.

Edited:

MYPATTERN can be for example: *

Thanks

Comment: Can you give some pattern examples? In your question, it looks like a normal file. Did you mean to say a regex?

Comment: Yes, a regex, like * . I have tried that way, but it does not work.

Comment: What about `find . -regex $myPatternpath`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, that's not a regex you want, but a wildcard. In that case, you could do something like:

```
for file in $HOME/folderName/*.xml; do
    if [ ! -f $file ] then assert=0; fi
done
echo $assert;
```

But of course, beacuse you are going through the files, the -f is implied. This would still be useful if checking for things like whether it's a folder, readable, etc...